# Javascript Object Notation Vs JSON Object

Tags: javascript, json

I was reading about Javascript and I came across javascript object notation and I was quite fascinated.

For example,

```
var myObject = {
    name: "Peter Foti",
    'course': 'JavaScript',
    grade: 'A', 
    level: 3
};
```

Why couldn't I do a JSON Object instead of using an object? When should we use Javascript objects as opposed to sending JSON Object?

Kinda confused here.

Comment: Your question makes very little sense: JSON is a serialisation standard (language independent) and JS object notation is just the way you define objects in JS. They are different things.

Comment: JSON is a data interchange format equivalent in syntax to JavaScript-the-language's object notation. With your above statement you create an object named `myObject` used in a running program. If you put the object's definition, just the part between and including the brackets `{ ... }`, into a file or transmit it as a message over the net, that's known to be in the JSON format.

Comment: `JSON` is a string

Comment: JSON never should've been called "JSON", because it's been causing confusion with JS *code* ever since. (Not sure what else to call it - "SOS" for "simple object serialisation"?)

Comment: You should read: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Answer (score 1):

You should use JSON (like XML or other structured language) in order to provide informations to other languages/system while Javascript object are type var live in javascript environment and therefore cannot be shared.